# Geoserver doesn't run properly on GCP Compute Engine: Wicket is not defined

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-compute-engine, geoserver

I'm trying to run geoserver on gcp with docker and docker-compose, here is the docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
   geoserver:
      image: "kartoza/geoserver:2.21.1"
      volumes:
        - ./geoserver_data:/opt/geoserver/data_dir
      ports:
        - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
      restart: on-failure
      environment:
        - GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir
        - GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=something_other_than_this
        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=something_other_than_this
      healthcheck:
        test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web || exit 1
        interval: 1m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
```

The website on the route [IP_ADDRESS]:8080/geoserver is this ugly html website
[image: ugly html website geoserver]

And the console logs are
[image: console logs]

On my local computer it works just fine. Firewall has every port open. No idea what to do after here. I tried adding an environment variable on the docker-compose file "GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED=true", but no luck.

edit: figured out the problem is only happening on firefox browser, chrome and edge, and mobile chrome works just fine.

Comment: are you following this [Kartoza docker-geoserver?](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver)

Comment: Yes, i am following that link. Read it again and nothing interesting popped up that could help

Comment: could be CSFR? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html

Comment: I'll check how I can disable it from the docker version

Comment: the problem is only happening on firefox, chrome and ie works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that when running on a vm-instance, adblocks are blocking a certain css resource. When disabling adblocks, the webpage runs just fine.